# How to close a p:dialog after a p:commandButton action?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:dialog` that shows after a `p:dataTable` row is clicked. I have a `p:commandButton` in the  `p:dialog` and it has an `action` like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Cambiar" action="#{adminUsuarios.cambiarPerfil()}" update="tblUsuarios" />
```

The method `cambiarPerfil()`:

```
public void cambiarPerfil() {
    // More stuff here
    this.listaUsuarios = null; // Clear the list
}
```

That works fine but **I want to close** the `p:dialog` after the `p:commandButton action`.

This is the dialog:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <!-- More stuff-->
    <p:dialog id="myDialog" widgetVar="editarDialog" header="Editar perfil de usuario #{adminUsuarios.usuarioSeleccionado.id_User}" resizable="false" width="400" showEffect="size" hideEffect="size">
        <p:commandButton value="Cambiar" action="#{adminUsuarios.cambiarPerfil()}" update="tblUsuarios" />
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add an `oncomplete` client side method in your `commandButton`.

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    ...
    <p:dialog id="myDialog" widgetVar="editarDialog" ...>
        <p:commandButton value="Cambiar" action="#{adminUsuarios.cambiarPerfil()}" update="tblUsuarios" oncomplete="editarDialog.hide();"/>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

If you're using PF5.0 you might need to change it to `oncomplete="PF('editarDialog').hide();"` where editarDialog is your dialog's `widgetVar`.

Comment: I also did it this way: `RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance(); context.execute("editarDialog.hide();");` inside the `cambiarPerfil()` method.

Comment: @KazMiller So did I* (* my  comment plagiarized from the movie The Shawsank Redemption)

Comment: use: oncomplete="PF('editarDialog').hide();" for PF 5.0 or higher